# How can I extract Data from netlib data as .mat format in python?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-algebra, linear-programming, net-library

I'm trying to solve netlib linear programming in python and have a big problem extracting data from netlib's data. for example, I want to solve the problem that its name is ["lpi_bgprtr.mat"](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/mat/LPnetlib/lpi_bgprtr.mat). The problem is as follows:

min c^T x s.t. Ax <= b, lb <= x <= ub

how can I extract matrix 'A' and vectors: 'c','b','lb' and 'ub'.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [scipy matlab IO module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/io.matlab.html)

```py
from scipy.io.matlab import loadmat
result = loadmat('./lpi_bgprtr.mat')
```